# How to reference DbContext in a class file .NET 6 EF

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor-pages

UPDATE: Add DI to the top.
@inject ApplicationDbContext db

Outside of razor pages.. I have a utility class and need to query the db from EF to get a value to populate in a razor partial.

In the _MenuPartial need to construct a class and get value.

```
@{
     WebMessageManagement wm = new WebMessageManagement(???dbcontext???);
     wm.GetMessageCount(); //returns int
 }
```

_MenuPartial code snippet:
[image]

In the WebMessageManagement class I have this:

```
  public class WebMessageManagement  
    {    
        ApplicationDbContext _db;
      
        public WebMessageManagement(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db; 
        }
        public int GetMessageCount()
        {
            var count = (from o in _db.WebMessages
                         where o.Id >= 3109
                         from t in o.Email
                         select t).Count();
            return count;
        }
    }
```

Normal razor pages seem to have the ApplicationDbContext injected. But I am creating a class outside razor pages. Do I need to set this context up again for non razor?

Comment: This isn't directly in relation to the solution you're asking about. But why does this WebMessageManagement  have a method *and* a property for getting the message count? Pick one or the other! Classes that contain state (such as properties) generally shouldn't also contain logic.

Comment: sorry that was me debugging, I just want to return an int. but was trying different ways. first option that worked i would go that way. lol

Comment: You don't re-create ApplicationDbContext...... you move ApplicationDbContext to its own csproj and assembly, and you SHARE it with others.    This is a part of "layer" development.  You don't put all your code in the WebApi layer.  You create a VS .sln with several csproj that are the "layers".    Then you binary share the layer that has the ApplicationDbContext in it.

Comment: My project uses the default EF & Identity setup. I have   data  and models and a Utility  projects all working fine with creting razor pages with models and passing the context via injection to my dataaccess proj classes. However, when I try to access the database context from the utility class outside the razor pages it dont have the db context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injection puts the object into the webrequest to the controller (99% of the time unless you are doing something very fancy). In this case you can just pass the context as a variable to the class function.

```
WebMessageManagement wm = new WebMessageManagement();
wm.GetMessageCount(dbcontext); //returns int
```

and then in the class file

```
public class WebMessageManagement  
{    
  
    public WebMessageManagement()
    {
        
    }
    public int GetMessageCount(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        var count = (from o in db.WebMessages
                     where o.Id >= 3109
                     from t in o.Email
                     select t).Count();
        return count;
    }
}
```

I think this will give you what you needed.

Comment: This works on the @Page model but not in a Partial Page not sure how to grab the contxt from a partial.

Comment: @Zippy Can you share in your post how you are adding your partial? In the frontend with a model?

Comment: I updated with a photo of the partial

Comment: Have you tried to inject it like you did the for UserManager and SignInManager? Seems like you are already doing what you need but with other dependencies. Not working for your DBContext?

Comment: OMG amazing, dont know if I like DI or scared of it. Thanks so much
@inject ApplicationDbContext db

Comment: Glad it worked out @Zippy! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject your new class as well. [Dependency Injection will figure out how to use your constructor and inject the ApplicationDbContext for you, given that its also registered for dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#multiple-constructor-discovery-rules)

`services.AddScoped<WebMessageManagement>()`